# How to read a file json in Angular 7 by using http module?

Tags: json, angular, http

#### Read JSON file in Angular 7

I am writing a simple program to output an array of data from a json file to a browser.

When I try to read a json file, I get an error:
Cannot read property 'code' of undefined.

#### app.module.ts :

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

   countries: any;

   constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

   ngOnInit(){
       this.http.get("...path to json file...")
       .subscribe((data) => this.displaydata(data));
   }

   displaydata(data) {this.countries = data;}
}
```

#### app.component.html :

```
<table>
<tr >
  <th>ID</th >
  <th>code</th >
  <th>name</th >
  <th>population</th >
</tr >
  <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
  <td>{{country.code}}</td>
  <td>{{country.name}}</td>
  <td>{{country.population}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While considering answers make sure you choose the fastest response. I am not asking you to mark mine, but i see you as a new user here! Just a heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
```

`ng-repeat` is AngularJS syntax. You want

```
  <tr *ngFor="let country of countries">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought about this problem for 2 days ))

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`ngFor`** with Angular instead of **`ng-repeat`** which is Angularjs syntax,

```
 </tr >
  <tr *ngFor="let country of countries">
  <td>{{country.code}}</td>
  <td>{{country.name}}</td>
  <td>{{country.population}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 7 there is no `ng-repeat`, use `*ngFor` instead

```
</tr >
  <tr *ngFor="let country of countries">
  <td>{{country.code}}</td>
  <td>{{country.name}}</td>
  <td>{{country.population}}</td>
</tr>
```